# Simple react component is not showing up on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component like this inside file `components/daw/index.js`. It should render just a text:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Daw extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="daw-container" key="daw-container">
                <span>DAW placeholder</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using the above component by another React component. Inside the file `components/media-viewer/VideoViewer/index.js` I have:

```js
export default class VideoViewer extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Daw/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The simple text `DAW placeholder` is *not* showing up on UI. Am I missing something obvious? Is something trivial missed?

```js
class Daw extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="daw-container" key="daw-container">
                <span>DAW placeholder</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class VideoViewer extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Daw/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<VideoViewer />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - see snippet. Can you edit the snippet until it reproduces your problem, so we can see it for ourselves? Until that happens, it'll be pretty hard to guess at what an answer would be

Comment: @CertainPerformance Right. I'm going to try to reproduce the problem. Great help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code snippet provided by @CertainPerformance shows that the answer is *no*. Nothing trivial is missed. The fault is somewhere else in the code.

```js
class Daw extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="daw-container" key="daw-container">
                <span>DAW placeholder</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class VideoViewer extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Daw/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<VideoViewer />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```